# Emberjs configure the Assetfile to scan nested Template folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I need to scan and compile a nested templates folder when the server starts. For that I'm using ember-skeleton. The following routine in Assetfile does well the job of scanning and compiling handlebars file as long as they are all in the templates folder.

```
  match 'templates/**/*.handlebars' do
    filter HandlebarsFilter
    filter TemplateFilter,
    #filter LoaderFilter,
      :module_id_generator => proc { |input|
        #input.path.sub(/^templates\//, "#{APPNAME}/~templates/").sub(/\.handlebars$/, '')
        input.path.sub(/^templates\//, "").sub(/\.handlebars$/, '')
      }
    if ENV['RAKEP_MODE'] == 'production'
      uglify {|input| input}
    end
    concat 'app.js'
  end
```

My list of file is getting larget by the ay and I want to classify files into folders such as

```
templates/products/
templates/products/index.handlebars
templates/products/new.handlebars                  
templates/products/edit.handlebars                  

templates/files/
templates/files/index.handlebars
templates/files/new.handlebars
templates/files/edit.handlebars
```

I want to modify the code listed above to be able to scan for handlebars files one level deeper, and execute the filter against the entries. This should be quite easy for someone who's acquainted with Ruby or Rails.

I tried with no luck the following, Also anyone can tell me how to debug such a routine, i tried to do a `print input` within the routine, the server crashed on me though :)

```
  match 'templates/**/**/*.handlebars' do
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about ember-skeleton, but looks like it's dead. I think you could consider using ember-rails instead

Comment: @sly7_7, what makes you think it's dead?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really an Ember question as much as it is a rake pipeline question. (Of course, the set of people using `rakep` who aren't using it for Ember appears to be very, very small...)

Comment: @pjmorse I've just looking at the project on github, and there is not commit over the last 5 months. Moreover it seems to rely on very old ember-version. ember-rails is currently supported, and has just been updated to the last 1.0-pre.4. I think iridium could also be taken in account. I've not used it yet, but it seems to a very good environment to develop client side application, and with ember-iridium, a good combo for ember apps.

Comment: @sly7_7 That's a reasonable conclusion, sure. The history of the project, however, seems to have been several months of inactivity followed by a burst of commits, so I wouldn't take five months as a sign of its demise - at least, not this project. The ember version is easily replaced... and if you need ember-rails, you probably shouldn't be using ember-skeleton anyway, as it's more useful for projects where the server side doesn't otherwise explicitly support Ember as ember-rails does.

Comment: @sly7_7 you can easily customize ember-skeleton, i'm using the latest ember version, even updated the way templates are stored and accessed. the only *issue* that i have is the one i mentioned in the question. ember-skeleton was an attractive solution when i was looking for a tool to pre-compile handlebars templates, because i'm not using rails as a backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `match 'templates/**/*.handlebars' do` is already taking care of scanning nested folders and there is not need to modify it, all i had to do is reflect the hierarchy in my template name

```
templateName: "product/index"
```